# How to combine insertion sort and merge sort to make it more efficient in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
#define ARRAYLENGTH 40
void InsertionSort(int * nums, int arrayLength);
void MergeSort(int * numlist1, int p, int r);
void Merge(int * numsl, int p, int q,int r);

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int nums1[ARRAYLENGTH],numsl[ARRAYLENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++)
    {
        nums1[i] = rand() % 10000;
    }
    cout << "arraylength = " << ARRAYLENGTH << endl;
    cout << "Before Sorting" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++)
    {
        cout << nums1[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;

    clock_t startTime1 = clock();
    InsertionSort(nums1, ARRAYLENGTH);
    clock_t endTime1 = clock();

    cout << "Running Time for Insertion Sort is " << (endTime1 - startTime1) / 1000 << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++)
    {
        cout << nums1[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "After Insertion Sorting" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++)
    {
        numsl[i] = rand() % 10000;
    }

    clock_t startTime2 = clock();
    MergeSort(numsl, 0, ARRAYLENGTH-1);

    clock_t endTime2 = clock();
    cout << "Running Time for Merge Sort is " << (endTime2 - startTime2) / 1000 << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++)
    {
        cout << numsl[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "After Merge Sorting" << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

this's the code for main function

```
 void InsertionSort(int * numList, int arrayLength)
    {
        // your code here
        int i,j,key;
        for (j=1;j<arrayLength;j++)
        {
            key=numList[j];
            i=j-1;
            while(i>=0 && numList[i]>key)
            {numList[i+1]=numList[i];
            i=i-1;
            }
            numList[i+1]=key;
        }
    }


 //this is the code of insertion sort




void MergeSort(int * numList, int p, int r)
    {

         if(p<r)
        {  
            int q=(p+r)/2;  
            MergeSort(numList,p,q);  
            MergeSort(numList,q+1,r);  
            Merge(numList,p,q,r);  
        }  

    }

    void Merge(int * numsl, int p, int q,int r)
    {
        int n1 = q - p + 1;
        int n2 = r - q;
        int * nums1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n1+1));
        int * nums2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n2+1));
        // your code here
        int i,j,k;
        for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
            nums1[i]=numsl[p+i];
        for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
            nums2[j]=numsl[q+j+1];
        nums1[n1]=10000;
        nums2[n2]=10000;
        i=0;
        j=0;
        for(k=p;k<=r;k++)
        {
            if (nums1[i]<=nums2[j])
                {numsl[k]=nums1[i];
                    i=i+1;}
            else
                {numsl[k] = nums2[j];
            j=j+1;}
    }
```

How to make the new combined algorithm using merge sort firstly then when have been divided in some degree  using insertion sort, and how to find the array length N?as is known to all, in small numbers, insertion sort is faster than merge sort, when it comes to large numbers, merge sort is much faster, I am thinking to make a combination of those two to make it more efficient? Specifically, to merge sort can be break down into divide and merge, I am considering when dividing in some level, using insertion sort , but I have trouble to how to find the level in which switch to insertion sort and how to implement it.

Comment: Please ask only one specific question.

Comment: If you want any faster sort, don't scrap the bubble, insertion, and merge soft. You can't combine them. But you can try. Try Heap Sort. If you succeed with it then try Quick Sort.

Comment: Check some distinct boundary values, profile code at different datasets and choose the best boundary (I expect that difference will be in range of some percents)

Comment: My teacher ask us to combine the merge sort and insertion sort  to make it process faster, teacher hinted  using merge sort firstly , when divide in some level then using insertion sort

Comment: And what stops you from making `if q-p>limit ...`  ?

Comment: Will std::set do most of this for you?

Answer (score 1):

Example code. I changed r to be the ending index (last + 1).

```
void MergeSort(int * numList, int p, int r)
{
    int n = r-p;
    if(n < 2)
        return;
    if(n <= 32){                  // 16 to 128 are reasonable values
        InsertionSort(numList, n)
        return;
    }
    int q=(p+r)/2;  
    MergeSort(numList,p,q);  
    MergeSort(numList,q,r);  
    Merge(numList,p,q,r);  
}
```

With the change to r, the calling code would be:

```
    MergeSort(array, 0, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
```

If performance is the goal, a bottom up merge sort is slightly faster. Most libraries use some variation of a hybrid insertion + bottom up merge sort. Top down merge sort is mostly used for educational purposes.